# Any notable large proof that took a long time before anyone checked it?

Tags: mathematics

Have there been any examples in the past where a large proof is claimed but nobody takes the time to check and that has been proved/disproved after a long time? I am not interested in proofs that were never taken seriously because they were unreadable (not even wrong).

Comment: Your description of the Mochizuki situation seems inaccurate. Scholze and Stix found an alleged flaw in 2018, but Mochizuki disagreed. Neither side has changed their mind since. As far as I know most mathematicians with an opinion think Scholze and Stix are right. That a non-mathematician is now offering $1 million, awarded at his sole discretion, for something that most mathematicians think was accomplished years ago suggests that it's not a good-faith offer, or at least not a well-informed one.

Comment: @benrg right, let me edit that

Comment: Further to benrg's comment, refer to the paper "[Why abc is still a conjecture](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/why_abc_is_still_a_conjecture.pdf)" [PDF]: "We, the authors of this note, came to the conclusion that there is no proof. We are going to explain where, in our opinion, the suggested proof has a problem, a problem so severe that in our opinion small modifications will not rescue the proof strategy. "

Comment: The latest on this is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435110/consequences-of-kirti-joshis-new-preprint-about-p-adic-teichm%c3%bcller-theory-on-th

Comment: The problem is not so much the length of the purported proof as the existence of a conceptual gap that has not been addressed.

Comment: "people have already pointed out inaccuracies in the proof since 2018" is still a misleading statement IMHO. When I heard of this prize, I laughed. Of course I know next to nothing about the proof, but if Scholze and Stix say it does not work, then it does not work, and this prize money is just a PR pitch. That's what I think, and I assume most mathematicians have a similar view.

Comment: I edited out everything, please this is not about Mochizuki

Comment: Regarding the main question: to have a large proof that is either accepted (or not), published, or even known to the public (such as HSMSE) without having undergone any sort of peer review process, seems strange to me.  The exceptions would be crackpots, incredibly niche fields with few experts, or the result of publishers who don't check for quality.  I'm curious if anyone can find such an example that answers your question.

Comment: @AndrewR. I am assuming that it was reviewed, but that it took a considerable time.

Comment: I am not sure how long a time you have in mind, but an  error in Kempe's verbose "proof" of the 4-color theorem went unnoticed for 11 years, see [Bray](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~ssam/old/19W-154/kempe.pdf). [Classification of finite simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups#History_of_the_proof) had tens of thousands of pages by 100 authors with gaps found and filled over half a century.

Comment: There are famous examples where it took long time (say, over 50 years) to find mistakes in proofs. It does not mean that nobody have read proofs before mistakes were found, just nobody have read **the entire proof close enough**.

Comment: Following up a bit on @MoisheKohan's comment: when the tone of an argument is happy-positive-confident, and subtly or overtly appeals to typical/standard physical or mathematical intuition, it may require an exaggerated critical-ness to see potential problems. Sometimes this occurs in subtle semantic misdirection or ambiguities, which might normally be harmless. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [classification of finite simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups) qualifies ("The proof consists of tens of thousands of pages in several hundred journal articles written by about 100 authors, published mostly between 1955 and 2004.")?

> 1983  Gorenstein announces the proof of the classification is complete,
> somewhat prematurely as the proof of the quasithin case was
> incomplete.
>
> 2004  Aschbacher and Smith publish their work on quasithin groups
> (which are mostly groups of Lie type of rank at most 2 over fields of
> even characteristic), filling the last gap in the classification known
> at that time.

Comment: Personally, I don't understand in what sense that theorem qualifies as a "proof that nobody wants to check", seeing as it's been contiuously revised since 1985.

Comment: I agree with @Gae.S. If several hundred articles exist (in peer-reviewed journals), each covering a part of the proof, it can hardly be completely unchecked.

Comment: @mdewey But also there's a group of people who have been writing it down for 30 years with the specific purpose of having it all in one place.

Comment: @Gae.S. : Maybe the theorem does not qualify as a "proof that nobody wants to check", as in OP's title, but it probably qualifies as "a large proof is claimed but nobody takes the time to check and that has been proved/disproved after a long time", as in OP's body. A more serious drawback of my answer is that the theorem was mentioned previously in Conifold's comment. I am sorry I missed it.

Comment: @akhmeteli Personally I don't believe that comments should have any claim to priority, since by design they are temporary and they need not abide to the same standards of quality as answers do.